# angular multiple ng-click function in one input

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there any way to bind multiple functions to ng-click? 
How to do that? If not possible, what is the alternative way?

```
<input type="radio" name="op1" ng-click="chkVal()" ng-value="">
```

I have two functions. chkVal() and deActivate(). I want to check the value and disable the radio with one click.

It may achieve with one function, but I want to know how to use multiple functions.

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call multiple functions in an ng-click by doing

```
<input type="radio" name="op1" ng-click="chkVal1();chkVal2();etc();" ng-value="">
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally prefer to not stack functions inside an html Attribute, my suggestion is to call one function that will call the other functions you need to keep your HTML tag clear and readable. like :

```
<input type="radio" name="op1" ng-click="chkVal()" ng-value="">
```

and inside your controller :

```
$scope.chkVal() = function(){
   callFunction1();
   callFunction2();
   callFunction3();
         .
         .
         .
}
```